# Uploading webshell in ASP.net application using directory-traversal and file-upload vulnerability

Tags: .net, file-upload, asp.net, directory-traversal

On my target site, I found two vulnerabilities, unrestricted file upload(to any directory) and directory traversal. I have two end points :

1- site.com/fileUp : uploads file
{

```
----Request Parameters---
file_data=<file>
file_name=123.jpg(can be used to upload file anywhere such as "../../bin/123.jpg")
```

}

2-site.com/fileDown  : download file
{

```
----Request Parameters---
file_name=123.jpg(can be used for directory traversal such as "../../etc/passwd")
```

}
file which is returned by fileDown is encoded in base64 and has ":jpg" attached at end of encoded string(still this path can be used to download files)

I can successfully download passwd, sshd_conf etc files and can upload files too

I want to upload web shell but I cant find root directory of application, when I pass file_name=../../test.asp to site.com/fileUp, it gives following error(I produced this error intentionally to gather more information otherwise I can upload files in /opt/site/(default location for uploaded files) and other directories without error):

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/' is denied
---StackTrace
SiteName.Server.Controllers.fileManegmentController.PictureUploaded() in 
D:\Projects\site\src\server\Controllers\FileManegment\fileManegmentController.cs:line 86
```

**Question 1**: Why it is giving window file system path in error while I can access files in linux file system

**Question 2**: What are potential effects of these two vulnerabilities

**Question 3**: How can I find root directory and can upload web shell, I tried reporting vulnerabilities and told them possibilities that it can lead to, but my HOD asked me to make POC for demonstration

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.